# Selenium to test Dygraphs

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, selenium-webdriver-c#

Is it possible to use selenium(C# bindings) to write automated tests for testing Dygraph charts?
If selenium does not support this? Are there any other tools which can be used?
http://dygraphs.com/

Greatly appreciate any advice in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, JS graphics libraries create a very complex DOM which makes difficult to verify behavior of the result - and Selenium is not properly focused on visual testing as well, which is a very important part of graphics.

For the functional problem, you can focus on unit testing, using something like [Jest.](https://jestjs.io/)

```
const chart = require('./chart');

test('chart has no labels', () => {
  expect(chart.createChart().getLabels()).toBe(null);
});
```

And for the visual testing, you can use something like [Percy](https://percy.io/), which will create baselines images of the **rendered** page on the first execution of a test and compare it to the results from subsequent executions.

[image]

Below you can find an [Ember test with Percy integrated](https://docs.percy.io/docs/ember-tutorial), where multiple snapshots are captured to be used in the future for comparison.

```
test('add todos', async function(assert) {
    await visit('/');

    await percySnapshot('Empty todo list');

    await fillIn('#new-todo', 'Bake a cake');
    await triggerKeyEvent('#new-todo', 'keydown', 13);

    await fillIn('#new-todo', 'Rake the lawn');
    await triggerKeyEvent('#new-todo', 'keydown', 13);

    await assert.equal(currentURL(), '/');
    await assert.equal(find('ul.todo-list li:first-child').innerText.trim(), 'Bake a cake');
    await assert.equal(find('ul.todo-list li:last-child').innerText.trim(), 'Rake the lawn');

    await percySnapshot('Todo list with 2 todos');
  });
});
```